# How would I compute a density matrix of a 2 qubit mixed state?

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, nielsen-and-chuang

I am currently reading Nielsen & Chuang, and one of the questions asks to calculate a density matrix with the following mixed states, how would I do this?
$$
|00> \;with \;probability \; 2/4 \\
|01> \;with\; probability\; 0\\
|10> \;with \;probability\; 1/4 \\
|11>\; with\; probability \;1/4$$

Answer (score 2):

$\rho = \dfrac{1}{2}|00\rangle \langle 00 | + 0|01\rangle \langle 01| + \dfrac{1}{4} |10\rangle \langle 10| + \dfrac{1}{4} |11\rangle \langle 11 | = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 \end{pmatrix}$

---

Note that $|00\rangle = |0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \cdot 1 \\ 1 \cdot 0 \\0 \cdot 1 \\ 0 \cdot 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and similarly, you can calculate that $|01\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $, and $|10 \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $, and lastly $|11\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $.

Now, $|00\rangle \langle 00| $ represents the [outer-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) and hence
$$|00\rangle \langle 00| = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \end{pmatrix}  $$

you can calculate the others and verify.

Comment: @KAJ266 How did you calculate the bra-kets? Do you multiply them elementwise?

Comment: @lambda I updated the answer to show you more details

Comment: @KAJ266 thank you, I appreciate the help, I calculated the others and I see how it works now