# How would I compute a density matrix of a complex qubit mixed state?

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, nielsen-and-chuang

I am currently reading Nielsen & Chuang, and one of the questions asks to calculate a density matrix with the following mixed state,

$$
\frac{1}{9}\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1 & −i \\
1 & 2 & -2i \\
i & 2i & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

and retrieving the probability of measuring

$$
|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! Please ask one focused question per post. It's no problem to submit multiple posts :-)

Comment: Regarding the first part of your question, does [this post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16171/10480) answer it?

Comment: @AdamZalcman Hi, sorry I didnt realise, my apologies. I did try a few times but I cant seem to get the results for either, also shall I submit a new post with these questions seperately or is it okay to keep this post as it is and remember for future?

Comment: You an edit this post so it contains only one question and submit the other as a separate post. That said, the first part of this question (density matrix of $|0\rangle$) is really a duplicate of the question I linked to above (just with different numbers substituted into the same formula).

Comment: @AdamZalcman Ah okay, ive edited the post for a single question. Would you be able to help me with the question by any chance?

Comment: Sure, wrote an answer. The question is a little unclear since it asks to calculate a density matrix but then proceeds to specify it, so AFAICT no density matrix needs to be actually calculated. I did calculate the probability you asked for. Note that this is really just a matter of substituting your inputs into the right formula, so I've added a reference to where to find the formula.

Comment: @lambda.: Please mention from which exercise this is taken. (page number of the book)

Comment: What book is this from? I don't think this is from Nielsen Chuang.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\rho$ denote the density matrix specified in the question. The probability of obtaining the result corresponding to $|0\rangle$ when measuring $\rho$ in the computational basis is

$$
p(0|\rho) = \mathrm{tr}(P_0\rho) = \mathrm{tr}(|0\rangle\langle 0|\rho) = \langle 0|\rho|0 \rangle = \frac{5}{9}
$$

where $P_0=|0\rangle\langle 0|$ is the projector onto the subspace spanned by $|0\rangle$. See equation $(2.159)$ on page 102 in Nielsen & Chuang where $M_m = P_0$ and note that $P_0=P_0^\dagger$ and $P_0^2 = P_0$.

Comment: Thank you, i've had a recap through that section and along with your explanation it makes perfect sense, I appreciate all the help and the warm welcome to QCSE :)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it was helpful :-)